# Algorithm to find best combination of sets

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, recursion, combinations

Assume I have `vector<plane> arriving` and `vector<plane> departing` filled with `plane` objects that are sorted according to their priority of landing(e.g. a `plane` with less fuel and more passengers should land before a plane with more fuel) or departing(e.g. a plane that has been waiting longest should depart first).  Planes that cannot land will circle(stay in the `arriving` vector) the runway and lose one unit of fuel each "turn".  The planes have a scheduled time of arrival or departure, and at that time they can land or depart.  Also, after this time, they will begin to lose fuel.  All actions(landing and departing) take 1 unit of time.

Assume also that I only have two runways that can only "process" two planes at a time(land/land, land/depart, depart/depart).  Is there a way to use programming to optimize the statistics of this situation(e.g. number of people killed, average wait time)?  In other words, I need to figure out if and how many planes I can depart without causing a crash.

I thought about recursively testing each possible situation, and testing them against each other somehow.  Are there any algorithms similar to this? Maybe backtracking?

The program is in c++, but any language in fine with me.  Thanks

**Edit**

Detailed example:

At time 0 I have 2 planes arriving, one with 1 unit of fuel and one with 0 unit of fuel.  However, I also have two planes scheduled to arrive at time 1, both that will have with 0 units of fuel at time 1.  In this situation, in order to "optimize" my statistics, I would need to land two planes at time zero(even though the plane with 1 unit of fuel doesn't *need* to arrive immediately) so that I can land the two planes at time 1.

Comment: Too little information given. For example, how would define "optimize"? How do you calculate "number of people killed"?

Comment: I would define optimize as fewest deaths, lowest average wait time.  I calculate the number of people killed by checking for planes that have less than zero units of fuel.

Comment: I would think then that you don't try to balance wait times against kills, since lives are worth more than delays, right? That is, a plane that's going to crash gets priority over a plane that is delayed regardless of the delay length, right?

Comment: correct.  But if I am able to depart planes without causing crashes, ideally I would.  I will try to "optimize" my question so that it evokes the strongest understanding while I wait for an answer.

Comment: You'll also need to know fuel consumption rates, in order to determine how long a plane can remain aloft. Also, how many minutes away is each plane from the airport? How long does it take to get a departing plane out? How long to get an arriving plane cleared from the runway?

Comment: Problems of this kind are called resource allocation problems. You might formulate your problem as constrained or unconstrained. Also you might want to take uncertainty into account. Searching for these keywords will turn up a lot of hits -- this is a vast and important topic, and much work has been done on it.

Comment: @RobertDodier thanks for the insight.  I'll look into this

Comment: If you want to minimize deaths, then perhaps allowing 2 planes to use a runway at the same time isn't a particularly great idea... Or, maybe "two runways that only two planes can use at a time" doesn't really mean what it seems to...

Comment: @twalberg Two planes cannot use a single runway at the same time.  I edited my question to clarify this

Comment: [Overkill paper](http://www.eurocontrol.int/eec/gallery/content/public/documents/Innovative_Studies/grants/2008/Review_of_airport_runway_scheduling.pdf);  [another](http://download.springer.com/static/pdf/132/art%253A10.1007%252Fs10288-011-0172-x.pdf?originUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flink.springer.com%2Farticle%2F10.1007%2Fs10288-011-0172-x&token2=exp=1492811550~acl=%2Fstatic%2Fpdf%2F132%2Fart%25253A10.1007%25252Fs10288-011-0172-x.pdf%3ForiginUrl%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flink.springer.com%252Farticle%252F10.1007%252Fs10288-011-0172-x*~hmac=8df5dfce45eb2af23da378c4da772651eaf2926f0fce8fafea5299f247a4beaa)